# Non-GUI based pin-entry for gpg

Tags: x11, remote, pinentry

I'm in the process of remotely viewing and selecting hundreds of images, some of which are encrypted with a symmetric key. I log in to the remote desktop machine using `ssh`. The viewing is not fast, but bearable once the viewer is open, but every time I try to decrypt one of the encrypted files with:

```
gpg -d img0424.png.gpg
```

it takes 2 minutes for the graphical pin-entry to show!  I was about to conclude the connection was broken.

How can I speed this up, or get a non-graphical version for the pin-entry? I cannot do `ssh -x` to disable X11 as I need it for viewing the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable X for a specific command line invocation by prefixing the command line with `DISPLAY=`:

`DISPLAY= gpg -d img0424.png.gpg`

That should give you the curses based pinentry interface instead of the GUI.

But it is probably more efficient to download all the files with `scp`. The data volume transferred when displaying over X is likely to be more than what `scp` consumes.

As @Benjamin suggested, there is also a more permanent solution on [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/521027/144040), where you change the pinentry program to be `pinentry-curses`.

Comment: +1 for suggesting viewing the files locally instead of over SSH. perhaps you could include a permanent solution in your answer as well, as per http://superuser.com/questions/520980/how-to-force-gpg-to-use-console-mode-pinentry-to-prompt-for-passwords